# Set the filter for one2many list showing based on the condition of many2one field? (Odoo 13)

Tags: filter, onchange, odoo-13, one2many

Im trying to set the filter for one2many list showing based on the condition of many2one field.

model_a.py :

```
 name = fields.Many2one('hr.employee')
 keya = fields.Many2one('model.b')
 num_a = fields.Monetary()
```

model_b.py:

```
 name = fields.Many2one('hr.employee')
 o_2_m = fields.One2many('model.a', 'keya', string='one2many list will be filter base on num_c')
 value_c = fields.Many2one('model.c', string='Value of C', required= True)
```

model_c.py:

```
 _rec_name = "code_c"
 code_c = fields.Char('Code', required= True)
 num_c = fields.Monetary()
```

By default, the one2many list will show all records if the user will not select record of value_c.

If the user selects record via value_c field which has created contains the value of num_c, the one2many list will be filtered for showing base on the value of num_c.

For Example: if the **num_a** in one2many field is: 15

Then when the user fills in **num_c** field is: 15 too

Then the one2many list just shows all the records which have the value: 15

That's the key condition for the filter of one2many list.

I'd tried with these codes in model_b.py :

```
 @api.onchange('value_c')
 def onchange_value_c(self):
    for rec in self:
       if rec.value_c and rec.o_2_m:
          for line in rec.value_c:
             find_c = self.env["model.c"].search([('num_c', '=', line.num_c)])
             find_a = self.env["model.a"].search([('num_a', '=', line.num_a)])
             #compare value of num_c with num_a
             if find_c.num_c == find_a.num_a:
                 for abc in rec.o_2_m:
                    return {'domain': {'o_2_m': [('num_a','=', abc.find_a.id)]}}
```

But it still not works. It still shows all one2many list's records, after selecting the record of value_c and click on the "Add a line" link.

Please help!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I'd solved my requirement.
Using onchange function in model_b.py like this:

```
@api.onchange('value_c') 
def onchange_get_value_c(self): 
  for rec in self: 
     if rec.value_c:
        for line in rec.value_c: 
            find_c = self.env["model.c"].search([('num_c', '=', line.num_c)])

            if find_c:
                 return {'domain': {'o_2_m': [('num_a','=', find_c.num_c)]}}
```

It works fine when the user selecting many2one 'value_c' field which has the value in field 'num_c', then when clicking on the "Add a line" link, it will show all records which have value in field 'num_a' match or equal to the value in field 'num_c'.
If the user selecting many2one 'value_c' field but not set the value for field 'num_c' or the value does not match or equal to the value in field 'num_a'. Then when clicking on the "Add a line" link, it will show nothing, and raise inform.